# How to copy top cmd output to clipboard in mac?

Tags: bash, macos

The below cmd works only for the static file or feeded data that exist; however to copy output for the running services like top cmds, I didn't find any source in MAC.

```
top | pbcopy
```

Is there any tweak for it?

[image]

Comment: Set the number of iterations to 1 for top: `top -l 1 | pbcopy`

Comment: I wish to delete this question since it's associated with Super User, which I don't aware. Can anyone help me? maybe Stackoverflow community - I don't have enough rights to delete this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pipe the output of the `top` command we have to set the number of samples to 1. In MacOS this can be done as follows:

`top -l 1 | pbcopy`